# How to read file, convert binary buffer to binary string and later convert the binary string to binary buffer again in C?

Tags: c, string, file, binary

I would like to write a program that could read a file, let's say myfile.bin, convert the buffer to binary 'string' ("101110111011..."), store that in a char* variable. Later, I would like to be able to convert that binary 'string' into a binary buffer again and create another file, let's say myanotherfile.bin, with the very same content of the first one.

Please note that I am not trying to read text from files.

I saw many people talking about how to do the first part but, until now, I couldn't find anyone talking about the second one (how to create a binary file from a binary string that was created from a previous file).

**UPDATE**

This is the code I am using to read a file and generate a 'binary string':

```html
#import <stdio.h>
#import <limits.h>
#import <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char buffer[32];
  FILE *file = fopen("myfile.bin","rb");
  if (file == NULL) { fclose (file); }

  size_t count;
  while ((count = fread(buffer, sizeof buffer[0], sizeof buffer, file)) > 0) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < count; j++ ) {
      for (int i = CHAR_BIT-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        fputc(buffer[j] & (1u << i) ? '1' : '0', stdout);
      }
    }
  }
  fclose(file);

  return 0;
}
```

The above code outputs a binary string such as: "1110011101101....".

This would be the first part. The second part would be to take that string and create a file. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

- First of all read your file and save all in a string.
- Then you can call this function:

  ```
  char * string_to_binarystring(char* s,int size)
  {
     char output[9];
     char * return_str = malloc(size*8+1);
     return_str[0] = '\0';
     while (*s)
     {
        itoa(*s, output, 2);

        strcat(return_str,output);
        ++s;
     }
     return return_str;
  }
  ```

  for example in this way:

  ```
  char string[] = "Hello World";

  puts(string_to_binarystring(string,strlen(string)));
  ```

  - At the end print your string into a file.

**Hint**:

For write into a binary file you need:

```
    char mystring[] = "Hello World";
    FILE *ptr_myfile;

    ptr_myfile=fopen("test.bin","wb");
    if (!ptr_myfile)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file!");
        return 1;
    }

    fwrite(mystring, strlen(mystring), 1, ptr_myfile);

    fclose(ptr_myfile);
```

**N.B.** you can find both `strlen` and `strcat` into `string.h`

---

## **EDIT:**

For rewriting the file as binary you need to convert your binary string into the original string (that you read from the file).

You can use this function:

```
char * binarystring_to_string(char* s,int size){
    char * return_str = malloc(size/8+1);
    int i;
    char * end;


    for(i = 0; i < size/8; i++){
        return_str[i] = bits_to_char(s);
        printf("\n%c",bits_to_char(s));
        s+=8;
    }
    return_str[i] = '\0';
    return return_str;
}
```

That for works need to use this:

```
char bits_to_char(char * num){
 unsigned char result = 0;
 int i;
 for ( i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
    result |= (num[i] == '1') << (7 - i);
 return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does your approach work for writing a binary sequence to file as well? I am not looking for writing string such as "hello world", instead, I would like to create a file from a binary string that I created from reading a previous file.

Comment: @DavidWilliam it prints a string. If is written "Hello World" or "111010010" it doesn't matter. The file you want to create should be binary or textual? (This doesn't matter with 0101010 to prints)

Comment: Ok. But my question is: from the string, can I recover the binary content? Think about a file like PDF, MP3, and so on. Not txt files.

Comment: @DavidWilliam I think you have some confused ideas. If you have a string you can get the binary code for each character of the string! if into the string is written: "01010110" it is a string.. no is binary rappresentation!

Comment: @DavidWilliam when you read your file you can use my function to convert into a **string** that contains the binary rappresentation of the previous string! Then you can write it in a binary file!

Comment: Please see my code. I updated the question. One file can be represented as a binary string (zero's and one's). The part I did. What I can't do yet is the opposite, from that string, recreate the file. Do you have any suggestions of how to recover the original file? Let's say we are talking about a mp3 file.

Comment: I will try your approach.

Comment: @DavidWilliam ok, i got what you need.. just a moment I'll edit my answer.. your question isn't very clear!!!!

Comment: @DavidWilliam is what you need?

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

it is quite obvious: do it in opposite direction, like in decimal but with power of 2:
0b10101010 convert to unsigned int like this:
2^8*1 + 2^7*0 + 2^6*1 + ... + 2^1*1 + 2^0*0.

Comment: How would you convert a string to its binary?

Comment: Question was:
convert the buffer to binary 'string' ("101110111011...")
Author wanted to convert binary values from file to its binary representation stored as string.
Question was how to convert it to binary again: kind of atoi function.